# Correctly type an async action which goes through redux-promise-middleware

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-promise-middleware

I'm using `redux-promise-middleware` for my `Redux` store setup and I'm trying to correctly type this async action:

**actions.ts**

```js
export const theAsyncAction = (): {
  type: "MY_ACTION_TYPE";
  payload: AxiosResponse<ApiResponse>; // [1]
} => {
  const url = "some url";
  return {
    type: "MY_ACTION_TYPE",
    payload: axios.get<ApiResponse>(url) // [2]
  };
};

export type Action = ReturnType<typeof theAsyncAction>;
```

And here's the switch block from the reducer:

**reducer.ts**

```js
import { Action } from './Action';

export default (state: State, action: Action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'MY_ACTION_TYPE' + '_FULFILLED': {
            const someProperty = action.payload.data; // [3]
            break;
        }
        ...
}
```

Obviously `[1]` and `[2]` are incompatible and I already know that. But since in `reducer.ts` I expect `[3]` to have the resolved `payload` object (not the `Promise`) I can't figure out how to do this.

Here's also my store setup:

**store.ts**

```js
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import rootReducer from './reducers';


const composedEnhancer = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware, thunkMiddleware));
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composedEnhancer);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is, the reducer is fine and compatible with the definition of the store and the action is just returning a promise, it's type isn't actually tied to the store, where in the code is it actually complaining about it being incompatible?

Comment: `MY_ACTION_TYPE_FULFILLED` in reducer expects `action.payload` to be a plain object. But in action definition `action.payload` is assigned to a promise.

The problem is `redux-promise-middleware` appends a `_FULFILLED` suffix to action name and dispatches it with promise's resolved data. 

In my action creator, `payload` is still a promise.